# How could could I reverse each string in the list?

Tags: python

So I've watched [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pAMgUB51XZA) video and wanted to draw one of the graphs shown. However, I was a beginner, and I quitted quickly. Now, I am back and a tiny bit more knowledgeable in Python. So, here is one of the functions I used:

```
def reverse(array):
    """Reverse the binary digits in the list"""
    if type(array) != list:
        raise ValueError('The argument must be a list!')
    else:
        bin = []
        for x in array:
            current = x
            reversed = ''.join(reversed(current))
            bin.append(reversed)


        return bin
```

However, when I pass an argument, It gives me nothing; just a literal nothing. 
An example:

```
print(reversed(['hi', 'bye']))
```

It prints nothing. Why is that?

Comment: Even with your typo, it shouldn't print *nothing*; `reversed` returns a an object, so you should see something like `<list_reverseiterator object at 0x00000000DEADBEEF>`.

Comment: Also note: You can't use the `reversed` function, while also naming a local variable `reversed`; you shadow the built-in. Luckily, you don't want `reversed` here anyway; `current[::-1]` (using the canonical reversing slice) is *much* more efficient than `''.join(reversed(current))`. Or just `x[::-1]`; there's no reason to give the same object two names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your functions is called `reverse()` and you're running `reversed()`. Try using `print(reverse(['hi', 'bye']))` and see if it works.